# Is there a way to execute same scenario concurrently and reuse the variables?

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

- I created several specific scenarios that sets a variables (see Image 1 below) and then calls PROCESS_RECORDS
- I created a generic ODI scenario (PROCESS_RECORDS) that performs approx. 6 steps; this scenario uses variables that are set in the calling scenario.
- I ran into issues when these scenarios would run concurrently; the variables would get overwritten and PROCESS_RECORDS would use the incorrect value.

**Image 1: Example of a scenario calling PROCESS_RECORDS:**

[image: Example of a scenario calling PROCESS_RECORDS]

**Image 2: PROCESS_RECORDS Scenario:**

[image: PROCESS_RECORDS Scenario]

To correct, I made several copies of the variables (in Image 1). However this required me to create several copies of other variables, procedures, etc. in PROCESS_RECORDS. And now my "generic" and "reusable" scenario is no more. I thought that the variables would be created as local vars and not global vars.

Is there a way to execute same scenario concurrently and reuse the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your main package, in the additionnal variables header of StartScen property box, you must select a project, a variable and set the value of the variable starting with # and keep the variable's name :

[image]

Second, in your package called by main package, you have to put your variable and choose type "Declare Variable" :

[image]